# Prevent decode \u200c character in NewtonSoft Json result

Tags: string, asp.net-web-api, formatting, json.net

I have Invisible \u200c character in data in some text in database when I return result in XML format in my ASP.net API result is shown correctly but when serialized it with Newtonsoft.Json "\u200c" string appear's in result. Is There any  setting for Newtonsoft to fix it?

json:

```
  {
            "rowClass": "someData",
            "fieldName": "someData",
            "description": "xxxx \u200cxxxxx",

  }
```

class:

```
public class Dto
{
    public string RowClass { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. [This sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDvkMz) doesn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is expected behavior.  In [JSON](http://www.json.org), unprintable characters in a string are encoded as `\u` + four hexadecimal digits, where the digits are the Unicode (UTF-16) representation of the character.  When you deserialize the JSON, the encoded hex digits will be converted back to the original character.  So, no, there is no way to "fix" this, because the serializer is working correctly.

Comment: Same problem here, trying to use yenc compression and \u9999 is just killing it :(